# How can I create root user on RHEL 7 after accidently destroying '/etc/passwd' file?

Tags: linux, operating-system, redhat

I accidently overwrote **/etc/passwd** file while I was logged in as 'root' user. After that, series of problems started.
First, I was unable to login as normal user as there was no user existed. I added the user again with same name using 'useradd' cmd but when I logged in as normal user, I was not able to login as 'root' user anymore because it said 'su: user root does not exist'. How can I be able to create 'root' user again with all root privileges.
P.S. There is no **'/var/backups/passwd.bak'** file available.

Comment: Belongs on Unix.stackexchange.com, but essentially it’s shutdown the system and boot into single user then create /etc/passwd

Comment: @JamesRisner. what text should I add into /etc/passwd ?

Comment: @AdilM, the text which was there. In a RHEL system it might be `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash` depending on setup and configuration. However, ususally there a more users, in example `bin`, `daemon`, `sync`, `shutdown`, `halt`, `dbus`, `polkit` and many more. What about them?